# Reverse engineering assembly code

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

Am am trying to learn assembly / reversing. I am struggeling to find documentation for idiv and imul with only one argument for example, and also understand for which argument is first and last in sub/add.  I  have been given the following code (with my understanding in comments)

```
start:
mov $1024, %rax ; move int value 1024 to register rax
mov $4096, %rbx ; move int value 4096 to register rbx
mov $2048, %rcx ; move int value 2048 to rax rcx
xor %rdx, %rdx ; rcx XOR rcx. rcx = 0
sub %rcx, %rbx ; sucstract rcx from rbx? rbx = 2048?
cmp %rbx, %rax ; compare rbx to rax
jge loopa ; if rax > rbx, jump to loopa ? (false first time)
jmp loopb ; else jump to loopb
loopa: ; start loop a 
cmp $4, %rdx ; compare int value 4 to register rdx
jg end ; if rdx > 4 jump to end 
inc %rdx ; rdx++ (rdx = 1 first time)
loopb:
xchg %rax, %rbx ; (switch value of rax and rbx)
idiv %rbx ; signed divide, but divide on what? 
add %rdx, %rax ; add rdx to rax ?
imul %rcx ; (multiple what? )
jmp loopa ; jump to loopa
end:
```

Is this a given dialect of x86 assembly? I have searched for instructions, and i see that they differ. Both in arguments, syntax and so on.

Comment: That's [at&t syntax](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dVariations.html). As for idiv and imul, they are of course described in minuscule detail in the [official intel instruction set reference manual](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/a4/60/325383-sdm-vol-2abcd.pdf), and various [copies on the internet](http://x86.renejeschke.de/).

Comment: `IDIV` works just like `DIV` (except that it treats the arguments as signed). The dividend is expected to be in `AX`/`DX:AX`/`EDX:EAX`. http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/IDIV.html

Comment: this is sort of incomplete AT&T syntax, the instructions can have even size suffix, i.e. `cmpq %rbx, %rax` because it's working with `qword` type registers, or `cmpb %bl, %al` if it would use only byte types, which is yet another source of confusion if you are not aware of AT&T syntax existence and somebody will show you such x86 assembly... (generally I suggest to rather learn + use Intel syntax, if you are free to choose)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably a mistype, but I want to make you notice anyway: in this line
`jge loopa ; if rax > rbx`,  `jge` means Jump if Greater **or Equal**, so `if rax >= rbx`. Remember that every AT&T (yes, it's a sort of dialect of intel syntax) instruction has this pattern: *instruction source, destination*. So for arithmetic or comparison instruction you have to start "thinking" from the second operand.

About `idiv` and `imul` instruction, you should read [this](http://flint.cs.yale.edu/cs421/papers/x86-asm/asm.html).